# Handle bad addresses in location columns

Tags: socrata

I am updating a very large dataset from a legacy system.  We want to map the data, but some of the row's addresses aren't mappable.  Either they are simply badly entered, or are PO Boxes.

I could live with some rows not getting mapped, but bad addresses cause the entire row to be rejected.

Has anyone had to deal with this situation?  What is the best way to handle it?  If we want the rows with bad addresses to be included in the dataset, do we need to forgo geo-locating?

Fixing the addresses is out of the question.

Comment: While I dig you up an answer, can you let me know what update method you're using? Web UI, DataSync, Upsert API, etc? If you're using DataSync, how is your update job configured?

Comment: Matt - Can you please file a ticket with our support team through either http://support.socrata.com, or by emailing support (at) socrata.com? Our support team can follow up with you through that channel.